# I'm new to web3 and blockchain development

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, nft, cryptography

I'm just starting out in web3 and blockchain technology. Can someone recommend any resources and where to start from

Answer (score 0):

You will thank me very much I think it is the best training you can follow: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4Rj_WH6yLgWe7TxankiqkrkVKXIwOP42&si=mxKOgLIOoeD7oo1C